# TSQL CASE WHEN THEN SYNTAX - USING REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

This actually applies to a prior question, [TSQL 2008 USING LTRIM(RTRIM and Still Have Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374888/tsql-2008-using-ltrimrtrim-and-still-have-spaces-in-the-data)

I am at the point of writing a very lengthy SELECT statement using OMG PONIES statement to remove NON NULL non visible characters

```
 (WHEN PropStreetAddr is NOT NULL THEN
    (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((REPLACE(PropStreetAddr, 
                                 SUBSTRING(PropStreetAddr, 
                                           PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%', 
                                           PropStreetAddr), 
                                 1), '') AS PropStreetAddr)
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LOAN_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 
     REPLACE( LOAN_NUMBER,SUBSTRING (LOAN_NUMBER,PATINDEX( ' %[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']% ' , ' ' ) as LOAN_NUMBER.
 ,CASE WHEN MERS_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 
     REPLACE(  MERS_ID,SUBSTRING (MERS_ID,PATINDEX( '  %[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']% ' , ' ' ) as MERS_ID 
 ...127 more lines of similar statements
```

As soon as I check the syntax I receive this error pointing to the first Case statement after SELECT:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 143
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Could someone help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some right parrens.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the END from your case statements.  You look like you could do with ELSEs in there as well, although these are not compulsory - if left off and nothing matches then you'll get a NULL.

```
CASE
 WHEN something then value1
 WHEN somethingelse then value2
 ELSE value3
END
```

Comment: +1 ...and the REPLACE(SUBSTRING(PATINDEX( is not making logical sense at the moment...

Comment: OMG, I have been looking at this code too long! I appreciate your comments & heads up.. Here is what see I need to fix this.. So very sorry I missed this earlier...
SELECT CASE  WHEN    LOAN_NUMBER IS NOT NULL  THEN REPLACE(  LOAN_NUMBER,SUBSTRING (LOAN_NUMBER,PATINDEX( '  %[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']% ' ,LOAN_NUMBER),  1) , ' ' ) End  as LOAN_NUMBER and so on