# Remove all spaces from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to remove all spaces from a string in SQL Server 2008?

`LTRIM(RTRIM('  a b '))` would remove all spaces at the right and left of the string, but I also need to remove the space in the middle.

Comment: By "all white spaces" do you mean only regular spaces?  Or, do you mean tabs, CR, LF, and other characters that may display as white space?

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I meant regular spaces

Answer (score 534, accepted):

Simply replace it;

```
SELECT REPLACE(fld_or_variable, ' ', '')
```

**Edit:**
Just to clarify; its a global replace, there is no need to `trim()` or worry about multiple spaces for either `char` or `varchar`:

```
create table #t (
    c char(8),
    v varchar(8))

insert #t (c, v) values 
    ('a a'    , 'a a'    ),
    ('a a  '  , 'a a  '  ),
    ('  a a'  , '  a a'  ),
    ('  a a  ', '  a a  ')

select
    '"' + c + '"' [IN], '"' + replace(c, ' ', '') + '"' [OUT]
from #t  
union all select
    '"' + v + '"', '"' + replace(v, ' ', '') + '"'
from #t
```

**Result**

```
IN             OUT
===================
"a a     "     "aa"
"a a     "     "aa"
"  a a   "     "aa"
"  a a   "     "aa"
"a a"          "aa"
"a a  "        "aa"
"  a a"        "aa"
"  a a  "      "aa"
```

Comment: What if there are multiple white spaces between words? REPLACE only removes one at a time. A user defined function should be written which removes multiple spaces.

Comment: This doesn't seem to replace trailing white spaces

Comment: It should replace all whitespace everywhere

Comment: It WILL remove all white spaces except for trailing. To remove trailing add TRIM(REPLACE(fld_or_variable, ' ', '')). The reason why it remove even multiple spaces is because... well it change every space characters to nothing wether the spaces are next to each other or not.

Comment: Replace removes all spaces even trailing one. If there are still apprently spaces in the data after this is done, it is likely they are not spaces but unprintable characters like tabs or carraige returns.

Answer (score 51):

I would use a REPLACE

```
select REPLACE (' Hello , How Are You ?', ' ', '' )
```

[REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 38):

If it is an update on a table all you have to do is run this update multiple times until it is affecting 0 rows.

```
update tableName
set colName = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(colName)), '  ', ' ')
where colName like '%  %'
```

Answer (score 26):

100% working

```
UPDATE table_name SET  "column_name"=replace("column_name", ' ', ''); //Remove white space

UPDATE table_name SET  "column_name"=replace("column_name", '\n', ''); //Remove newline

UPDATE table_name SET  "column_name"=replace("column_name", '\t', ''); //Remove all tab
```

You can use `"column_name"` or `column_name`

Thanks

Subroto

Comment: I had to use `select replace(replace(replace(varcharColumn,char(13),''),char(10),''),' ','')` to remove all newlines and spaces from a `varchar` column. If I used '\n' and '\r' instead of char(13) and char(10) it didn't work.

Comment: to execute this, it's needed to run "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;"

Comment: That was what I needed! Thank you!!

Comment: Exactly what was required. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

[`REPLACE()` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
REPLACE(field, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 14):

**[Reference taken from this blog:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/01/sql-server-script-to-remove-extra-spaces-from-a-string/)**

**First, Create sample table and data:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_RemoveExtraSpaces
(
     Rno INT
     ,Name VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO tbl_RemoveExtraSpaces VALUES (1,'I    am     Anvesh   Patel')
INSERT INTO tbl_RemoveExtraSpaces VALUES (2,'Database   Research and     Development  ')
INSERT INTO tbl_RemoveExtraSpaces VALUES (3,'Database    Administrator     ')
INSERT INTO tbl_RemoveExtraSpaces VALUES (4,'Learning    BIGDATA    and       NOSQL ')
GO
```

**Script to SELECT string without Extra Spaces:**

```
SELECT
     [Rno]
    ,[Name] AS StringWithSpace
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Name],CHAR(32),'()'),')(',''),'()',CHAR(32)))) AS StringWithoutSpace
FROM tbl_RemoveExtraSpaces
```

**Result:**

```
Rno         StringWithSpace                                 StringWithoutSpace
----------- -----------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------
1           I    am     Anvesh   Patel                      I am Anvesh Patel
2           Database   Research and     Development         Database Research and Development
3           Database    Administrator                       Database Administrator
4           Learning    BIGDATA    and       NOSQL          Learning BIGDATA and NOSQL
```

Comment: Do you realize the OP wanted to remove ALL spaces instead of replacing multiple spaces with a single one?

Comment: This should have been downvoted due to the answer is not as required by the OP, but instead it got 4 upvotes. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mr.J and now it has 9. Crazy world.

Answer (score 12):

t-sql replace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

replace(val, ' ', '')

Answer (score 11):

This does the trick of removing the spaces on the strings:

```
UPDATE
    tablename
SET
    columnname = replace(columnname, ' ', '');
```

Answer (score 9):

If there are multiple white spaces in a string, then replace may not work correctly. For that, the following function should be used.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveAllSpaces
(
    @InputStr varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
declare @ResultStr varchar(8000)
set @ResultStr = @InputStr
while charindex(' ', @ResultStr) > 0
    set @ResultStr = replace(@InputStr, ' ', '')

return @ResultStr
END
```

Example:

```
select dbo.RemoveAllSpaces('aa  aaa       aa aa                 a')
```

Output:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: "@InputStr" should be "@ResultStr" in the body of the while loop.

Comment: @jjoelson would you mind to create this function and test it before pointing out mistakes?

Comment: Sorry, I was working under your above assumption that REPLACE only removes one at a time, in which case this function would cause an infinite loop for inputs with multiple spaces. In reality, the while loop isn't even necessary at all.

Comment: Farhan, if REPLACE worked the way you think it does then @jjoelson's first comment is correct. Otherwise you'll have an infinite loop because InputStr never changes so ResultStr will always be the first REPLACE result. The reason your code works is because REPLACE is needed only 1 time. It's never called a second time no matter what string you throw at it. Add a counter and print it out with each iteration. It'll always be 1. REPLACE(InputStr, ' ', '') will remove every space with one call.

Answer (score 8):

```
replace(replace(column_Name,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use like this, if normal spaces are not removed by LTRM or RTRM

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column_data, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')))
```

Comment: Had the same issue i.e. a whitespace at the start of the email string. I can confirm that this worked for me - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you need to TRIM spaces in all columns, you could use this script to do it dynamically:

```
--Just change table name
declare @MyTable varchar(100)
set @MyTable = 'MyTable'

--temp table to get column names and a row id
select column_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column_name) as id into #tempcols from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar') and TABLE_NAME = @MyTable

declare @tri int
select @tri = count(*) from #tempcols
declare @i int
select @i = 0
declare @trimmer nvarchar(max)
declare @comma varchar(1)
set @comma = ', '

--Build Update query
select @trimmer = 'UPDATE [dbo].[' + @MyTable + '] SET '

WHILE @i <= @tri 
BEGIN

    IF (@i = @tri)
        BEGIN
        set @comma = ''
        END
    SELECT  @trimmer = @trimmer + CHAR(10)+ '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = LTRIM(RTRIM([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))'+@comma
    FROM    #tempcols
    where id = @i

    select @i = @i+1
END

--execute the entire query
EXEC sp_executesql @trimmer

drop table #tempcols
```

Answer (score 3):

To make all of the answers above complete, there are additional posts on StackOverflow on how to deal with ALL whitespace characters (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character for a full list of these characters):

- [TSQL 2008 Using LTrim(RTrim and still have spaces in the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374888/tsql-2008-using-ltrimrtrim-and-still-have-spaces-in-the-data/12600716?s=1|36.5590#12600716)
- [How do I remove non-breaking spaces from a column in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214848/how-do-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-sql-server/15215094?s=2|36.4102#15215094)
- [What's a good way to trim all whitespace characters from a string in T-SQL without UDF and without CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245812/whats-a-good-way-to-trim-all-whitespace-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql-witho/35247507?s=3|22.0859#35247507)

Answer (score 3):

*this is useful for me:*

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@String VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,CHAR(10),'[]'),CHAR(13),'[]'),char(9),'[]'),CHAR(32),'[]'),'][',''),'[]',CHAR(32))));
END
GO
```

.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove spaces,-, and another text from string then use following :

suppose you have a mobile number in your Table like '718-378-4957' or
 ' 7183784957' and you want replace and get the mobile number then use following Text.

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(MobileNo,'-',''),'(',''),')',''),' ','') from EmployeeContactNumber
```

Result :-- 7183784957

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip, in case you are having trouble with the replace function, you might have the datatype set to nchar (in which case it is a fixed length and it will not work).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and replace / trim did the trick..see below.

```
update table_foo 
set column_bar  = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(column_bar)), '  ', '')
```

before and after :

```
old-bad:  column_bar    |   New-fixed:   column_bar
       '  xyz  '        |                'xyz'   
       '  xyz  '        |                'xyz' 
       '  xyz  '        |                'xyz' 
       '  xyz  '        |                'xyz' 
       '  xyz  '        |                'xyz' 
       '  xyz  '        |                'xyz'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check and Try the below script (Unit Tested)-

```
--Declaring
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(col_1 VARCHAR(100));

--Test Samples
INSERT INTO @Tbl (col_1)
VALUES
('  EY     y            
Salem')
, ('  EY     P    ort       Chennai   ')
, ('  EY     Old           Park   ')
, ('  EY   ')
, ('  EY   ')
,(''),(null),('d                           
    f');

SELECT col_1 AS INPUT,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(col_1,CHAR(10),' ')
        ,CHAR(11),' ')
        ,CHAR(12),' ')
        ,CHAR(13),' ')
        ,CHAR(14),' ')
        ,CHAR(160),' ')
        ,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),' ')
    ,CHAR(9),' ')
    ,' ',CHAR(17)+CHAR(18))
    ,CHAR(18)+CHAR(17),'')
    ,CHAR(17)+CHAR(18),' ')
    )) AS [OUTPUT]
FROM @Tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spaces in a string left and right. To remove space in middle use `Replace`.

You can use `RTRIM()` to remove spaces from the right and `LTRIM()` to remove spaces from the left hence left and right spaces removed as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) = LTRIM(RTRIM("Bob alias baby"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax for replacing a specific characters:**

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

For example in the string "HelloReplaceThingsGoing" Replace word is replaced by How

```
SELECT REPLACE('HelloReplaceThingsGoing','Replace','How');
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional version (udf) that removes spaces, cr, lf, tabs or configurable.

```
select Common.ufn_RemoveWhitespace(' 234   asdf   wefwef 3  x   ', default) as S
```

Result: '234asdfwefwef3x'

```
alter function Common.RemoveWhitespace
(
    @pString nvarchar(max),
    @pWhitespaceCharsOpt nvarchar(max) = null -- default: tab, lf, cr, space 
)  
returns nvarchar(max) as
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose:   Compress whitespace

    Example:  select Common.ufn_RemoveWhitespace(' 234   asdf   wefwef 3  x   ', default) as s 
              -- Result: 234asdfwefwef3x

    Modified    By          Description
    ----------  ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018.07.24  crokusek    Initial Version 
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
begin    
    declare 
        @maxLen bigint = 1073741823, -- (2^31 - 1) / 2 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270085/538763)
        @whitespaceChars nvarchar(30) = coalesce(
            @pWhitespaceCharsOpt, 
            char(9) + char(10) + char(13) + char(32));  -- tab, lf, cr, space

    declare
        @whitespacePattern nvarchar(30) = '%[' + @whitespaceChars + ']%',
        @nonWhitespacePattern nvarchar(30) = '%[^' + @whitespaceChars + ']%',
        @previousString nvarchar(max) = '';

    while (@pString != @previousString)
    begin
        set @previousString = @pString;

        declare
            @whiteIndex int = patindex(@whitespacePattern, @pString);

        if (@whiteIndex > 0)
        begin                   
            declare 
                @whitespaceLength int = nullif(patindex(@nonWhitespacePattern, substring(@pString, @whiteIndex, @maxLen)), 0) - 1;                

            set @pString = 
                substring(@pString, 1, @whiteIndex - 1) + 
                iif(@whiteSpaceLength > 0, substring(@pString, @whiteIndex + @whiteSpaceLength, @maxLen), '');
        end        
    end        
    return @pString;
end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the replace works only with one string each time.
I had a string like this "**Test           MSP**" and I want to leave only one space.

I used the approach that @Farhan did, but with some modifications:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceAll
(
    @OriginalString varchar(8000),
    @StringToRemove varchar(20),
    @StringToPutInPlace varchar(20)
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
declare @ResultStr varchar(8000)
set @ResultStr = @OriginalString
while charindex(@StringToRemove, @ResultStr) > 0
    set @ResultStr = replace(@ResultStr, @StringToRemove, @StringToPutInPlace)

return @ResultStr
END
```

Then I run my update like this

```
UPDATE tbTest SET Description = dbo.ReplaceAll(Description, '  ', ' ') WHERE ID = 14225
```

Then I got this result:
**Test MSP**

Posting here if in case someone needs it as I did.

Running on:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question was about simply replacing *spaces*, but should you need to replace ALL whitespace, you can use the TRANSLATE function (since Sql Server 2019) to convert a given list of characters to something easier to replace.  Then wrap it with the REPLACE function.

This saves repeated calls:

```
DECLARE @Whitespace CHAR(4) = CHAR(0) + CHAR(9) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
SELECT REPLACE(
    TRANSLATE(' TEST    ', @Whitespace, '    '),
    ' ', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I share a solution that -in my opinion- is very fast, but somewhat tedious to install. It works fine for me on Microsoft **SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3)**:

1. Install the **Sql Regex assembly** on the server where the database is installed. The installation steps are in the following link:
   https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex#installation
2. Create in the database the **function dbo.TRIM**, which is based on The RegexReplace() scalar function ( https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex#replace ):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TRIM](@text NVARCHAR(MAX))
  RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) --WITH SCHEMABINDING 
BEGIN

-- This function removes:
-- 1. invisible characters,
-- 2. repeated blank spaces and
-- 3. the spaces at the beginning and at the end of the text.

    RETURN (CASE
        WHEN @text is NULL 
            THEN NULL
        ELSE

            dbo.RegexReplace((dbo.RegexReplace(dbo.RegexReplace(@text, N'['+Nchar(0)+N'-'+Nchar(32)+Nchar(8192)+N'-'+Nchar(8202)+Nchar(160)+Nchar(5760)+Nchar(6158)+Nchar(8232)+Nchar(8233)+Nchar(8239)+Nchar(8287)+Nchar(65440)+Nchar(12288) +N']+', N'[}'), N'[\[\}]+', ' ')), N'^\s+|\s+$','')  

    END);
END
GO
```

....................

How to use:

```
declare @txt NVARCHAR(MAX) = N' Hello,'+Nchar(12288)+N'          my      '+NCHAR(160)+N'name'+Nchar(0)+N'     is John'+NCHAR(11)+N'            Doe';

select dbo.TRIM(@txt) as Result -- Result: "Hello, my name is John Doe"
```

....................

**Update:**

To completely **remove all spaces**, you can create the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TRIM_SPACES](@text NVARCHAR(MAX))
  RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) --WITH SCHEMABINDING 
BEGIN
    RETURN (CASE WHEN @text is NULL THEN NULL ELSE
            dbo.RegexReplace(@text, N'['+Nchar(0)+N'-'+Nchar(32)+Nchar(8192)+N'-'+Nchar(8202)+Nchar(160)+Nchar(5760)+Nchar(6158)+Nchar(8232)+Nchar(8233)+Nchar(8239)+Nchar(8287)+Nchar(65440)+Nchar(12288) +N']+', N'')
    END)
END
GO
```

....................

How to use:

```
declare @txt NVARCHAR(MAX) = N' Hello,'+Nchar(12288)+N'          my      '+NCHAR(160)+N'name'+Nchar(0)+N'     is John'+NCHAR(11)+N'            Doe';

select dbo.TRIM_SPACES(@txt) as Result -- Result: "Hello,mynameisJohnDoe"
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that everybody keeps referring to a single REPLACE function. Or even many calls of a REPLACE function. But when you have dynamic output with an unknown number of spaces, it wont work. Anybody that deals with this issue on a regular basis knows that REPLACE will only remove a single space, NOT ALL, as it should. And LTRIM and RTRIM seem to have the same issue. Leave it to Microsoft.
Here's a sample output that uses a WHILE Loop to remove ALL CHAR(32) values (space).

```
DECLARE @INPUT_VAL  VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @OUTPUT_VAL VARCHAR(8000)

SET @INPUT_VAL = '      C               A                         '
SET @OUTPUT_VAL = @INPUT_VAL
WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), @OUTPUT_VAL) > 0 BEGIN
    SET @OUTPUT_VAL = REPLACE(@INPUT_VAL, CHAR(32), '')
END

PRINT 'START:' + @INPUT_VAL + ':END'
PRINT 'START:' + @OUTPUT_VAL + ':END'
```

Here's the output of the above code:

```
START:      C               A                         :END
START:CA:END
```

Now to take it a step further and utilize it in an UPDATE or SELECT statement, change it to a udf.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_RemoveSpaces (@INPUT_VAL    VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @OUTPUT_VAL VARCHAR(8000)
SET @OUTPUT_VAL = @INPUT_VAL
-- ITTERATE THROUGH STRING TO LOOK FOR THE ASCII VALUE OF SPACE (CHAR(32)) REPLACE IT WITH BLANK, NOT NULL
WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), @OUTPUT_VAL) > 0 BEGIN
    SET @OUTPUT_VAL = REPLACE(@INPUT_VAL, CHAR(32), '')
END

RETURN @OUTPUT_VAL
END
```

Then utilize the function in a SELECT or INSERT statement:

```
UPDATE A
SET STATUS_REASON_CODE = WHATEVER.dbo.udf_RemoveSpaces(STATUS_REASON_CODE)
FROM WHATEVER..ACCT_INFO A
WHERE A.SOMEVALUE = @SOMEVALUE

INSERT INTO SOMETABLE
(STATUS_REASON_CODE)
SELECT WHATEVER.dbo.udf_RemoveSpaces(STATUS_REASON_CODE)
FROM WHATEVER..ACCT_INFO A
WHERE A.SOMEVALUE = @SOMEVALUE
```

Comment: "REPLACE will only remove a single space." ...really? This simple demo suggests not: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=789d24b980741308871eba17722820c0 . Have you got an example of where that wouldn't work?