# Removing spaces in concatenated string column in a view

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have run the following script to create a view which provides the results I want:

```
SELECT     ACTNUMBR_1, ACTNUMBR_2, ACTNUMBR_3, ACTNUMBR_1 + '-' + ACTNUMBR_2 AS Match_Account, ACTNUMBR_1 + '-' + ACTNUMBR_2 + '-' + ACTNUMBR_3 AS Full_Account_Number
FROM dbo.GL00100
```

but my data has gaps in the Match_Account and Full_Account_Number columns.  See the output below:

[image]

I would like my account numbers to appear like - A100-000 OR A100-000-000.

What is the easiest way to remove all spaces on this view to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Also, duplicate of [Removes all white spaces of a string in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/removes-all-white-spaces-of-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to remove your spaces:

```
SELECT ACTNUMBR_1, ACTNUMBR_2, ACTNUMBR_3, 
    REPLACE(ACTNUMBR_1 + '-' + ACTNUMBR_2, ' ', '') AS Match_Account, 
    REPLACE(ACTNUMBR_1 + '-' + ACTNUMBR_2 + '-' + ACTNUMBR_3, ' ', '') AS Full_Account
```