# How do I remove non-breaking spaces from a column in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to remove a non-breaking space (`CHAR 160`) from a field in my table. I've tried using functions like `RTRIM()` to get rid of it, but the value is still there.

What do I need to do to remove the non-breaking space from the column?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try using [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET Your_Column = REPLACE(Your_Column, NCHAR(0x00A0), '')
WHERE Id = x
```

Answer (score 20):

You could also use

```
REPLACE(The_txt, NCHAR(160), ' ')
```

Comment: I like this but for clarity perhaps:

REPLACE(The_txt, NCHAR(160), NCHAR(32))

Comment: NCHAR was not working for me. CHAR(160) worked. As said by @Malikarjun, use CHAR instead of NCHAR.

Answer (score 7):

If the above solutions does not work, try CHAR instead of NCHAR

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET Your_Column = REPLACE(Your_Column, CHAR(160), '')
WHERE Id = x
```

CHAR worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

NCHR(160) worked for me.

Oracle 19c.