# How to remove non-breaking spaces from a column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, trim, non-breaking-characters

Trying to remove a non-breaking space from a field without any success. I've tried

```
execute <<-SQL
  UPDATE customers
  SET name = TRIM (name)
SQL
```

but this removes only spaces. It's similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214848/how-do-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-sql-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa%22this%22) but I need it for Postgres (Postgres complains `syntax error at or near "x00A0"`) and also I need only trimming i.e it has to remove only at the beginning and at the end of the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass the character as the second argument of `trim()`:

```
update customers
set name = trim(name, chr(160))
```