How to remove special character without knowing the type of special character?
I am using snowflake and I am parsing an email message for a certain field. I found that only 2 records have a whitespace in the front. I have used trim, tried various types of char replace (9,10,13,14,11, some more but i forgot however it is still presistent.
The reason why I think this might be a special Character is if I do a like '% DYING GASP%' it won't return. But '%DYING GASP%' will.
I have tried using this article from Snowflake's community to find whether or not it has a special character, but the odd row isn't appearing here.
This is the current code, the first 3 replace; 9,10,13 is necessary the other 2 is just me trying out different character types.
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(c.description), 'ROOTCAUSE :\s*([^:\n]+)', 1, 1, 'e', 1) , CHAR(13), '') , CHAR(10), '') , char(9), '') , char(14), '') , char(11), '')
Part of the original message:
".....
Rootcause :    DYING GASP
Action :    No Action 
....."
I also will attach the image of the cell in question.Example
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Edit: The query is a snippet of a long casewhen. The beginning of the case when already has a TRIM.

What is the exact result of SELECT TO_BINARY(c.description)

@Charlieface snowflake returns this error: The following string is not a legal hex-encoded value: 'Case ID :    XXXXX

@Charlieface if i do the select on the regex'ed column, this is the error message:
The following string is not a legal hex-encoded value: '    DYING GASP'

Sorry try TO_BINARY(c.description, 'utf-8')

I used the rootcause column (the output of the regexp). If you need the message prior being parsed, will trim others first since there are some cust data.
Anyways, this is the output of the root cause (the one with the issue)
C2A0C2A020C2A04459494E472047415350

Well C2A0 is the UTF8 encoding for NO-BREAK SPACE, which is emphatically not a whitespace character as noted in many places. So not surprising it wouldn't trim it, it's specifically designed not to be considered whitespace. How did you get that in your text in the first place?

See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861235/how-to-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-postgres

Hey, that works. Thanks a lot!
The user mentions that this is the body of an email, the email was sent by help-desks with a pre-determined template. But aside from the template, it is manually typed I guess haha.

Try this


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CLEANSTRING("input" varchar, "replacement" varchar)

RETURNS varchar

LANGUAGE JavaScript

AS

$$

  var output = "";

  if(input == undefined){

  return input

  }

  else{

  for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){

    if (input.charCodeAt(i) >= 32 && input.charCodeAt(i) <= 127) {

      output += input.charAt(i);

    }

    else {

    output += replacement

    }

  }

  return output;

}

$$

 

SELECT CLEANSTRING('C&I CORRESP RCVD �REQ DUPLICATE STATEMEN','');  




Hey it works! Just needed to add trim to the column and its fine. Thank you!

Whoa what happens if your text has $ or Á or ø or anything not in simple English A-Z you want to delete that??
