# Possible (invisible) characters in text pasted from Excel or XML to a TSQL query

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

My ASP.Net application receives an uploaded Excel file, then converts to XML to pass as a stored procedure parameter for processing.  This file contains lots of entries that are text-matched to find the corresponding value.

Today (after working perfectly for years) three seemingly identical values caused mixed results on the text match.  I can only illustrate with an example:

[image: Results]

- The first value is the original value within Excel (copied from the
  spreadsheet).
- The second value is that which the web application
  saves to XML, and is the raw value taken from the profiler showing
  the parameter values
- The third value is that which currently exists
  in the table

The code is pasted from SSMS:

```
SELECT SkillGroupTitle FROM tbl_SkillGroups WHERE SkillGroupTitle = N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'; -- pasted from Excel
SELECT SkillGroupTitle FROM tbl_SkillGroups WHERE SkillGroupTitle = N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'; -- pasted from xml
SELECT SkillGroupTitle FROM tbl_SkillGroups WHERE SkillGroupTitle = N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'; -- pasted from SQL table (existing value)
```

Can somebody please advise what is happening here?  All values *appear* identical visually, but there's clearly *something* different within the inbound values from Excel.

### Update

Pasting the two values into a hex converter, there are indeed three differences.

Excel data:

```
51 75 61 6c 69 74 79 a0 41 73 73 75 72 61 6e 63 65 a0 49 6e 73 74 72 75 63 74 69 6f 6e 20 28 51 41 49 29 0a
                     --                            --                                                    --
```

SQL data:

```
51 75 61 6c 69 74 79 20 41 73 73 75 72 61 6e 63 65 20 49 6e 73 74 72 75 63 74 69 6f 6e 20 28 51 41 49 29
```

Can anyone shed any light here please?

Comment: Hmm interesting.  I'll update the question with the findings (although I'm still clueless what these differences are within the string)

Comment: a0 is a non-breaking space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space.  You are going to need to clean the string before you send it off to be queried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214848/how-do-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-sql-server

Comment: Amazing pointers, thank you.  I got it to match with `REPLACE(N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)', NCHAR(0x00A0), NCHAR(0x0020))`.  Please migrate your comment as an answer if you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

First, to identify hidden characters causing strings not to be equal you can leverage [ngrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) like this:

```
WITH tbl_SkillGroups(dSource, SkillGroupTitle) AS 
(
SELECT 'Excel', N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)' -- pasted from Excel
UNION ALL
SELECT 'XML',   N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'+CHAR(10) -- pasted from xml
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SQL',   N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'+CHAR(13) -- pasted from SQL table (existing value)
)
SELECT 
  [Source]   = ts.dSource,
  Position   = ng.Position,
  Token      = ng.Token, 
  asciiValue = ASCII(ng.Token)
FROM        tbl_SkillGroups                     AS ts
CROSS APPLY samd.ngrams8k(ts.SkillGroupTitle,1) AS ng
--WHERE       ng.Position > 32 -- Zoom into the last few characters
```

**Returns:**

```
Source Position  Token   asciiValue
------ --------- ------- -----------
Excel  33        A       65
Excel  34        I       73
Excel  35        )       41  -- Only 35 characters 
XML    33        A       65
XML    34        I       73
XML    35        )       41
XML    36                10 -- 36th character is a CHAR(10) (Looks like a space)
SQL    33        A       65
SQL    34        I       73
SQL    35        )       41
SQL    36                13 -- 36th character is a CHAR(13) (Also looks like a space)
```

NEXT, to clean hidden characters from your inputs you can use [PatReplace8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patreplace8k).

```
WITH tbl_SkillGroups(dSource, SkillGroupTitle) AS 
(
SELECT 'Excel', N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)' -- pasted from Excel
UNION ALL
SELECT 'XML',   N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'+CHAR(10) -- pasted from xml
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SQL',   N'Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)'+CHAR(13) -- pasted from SQL table (existing value)
)
SELECT SkillGroupTitle
FROM tbl_SkillGroups as ts
CROSS APPLY PatReplace8K(ts.Skillgrouptitle,'[^a-zA-Z ()]','') as pr
WHERE SkillGroupTitle = pr.NewString
```

**Returns:**

```
SkillGroupTitle
------------------------------------
Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)
Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)
Quality Assurance Instruction (QAI)
```

Here, PatReplace8k would remove any characters that didn't match the pattern (letters, spaces and parentheses) thus making these three values equal.

Comment: Thanks.  The challenge with this is that the table accepts characters from different languages (e.g. English and Norwegian).  I'm not sure if that makes the Regex pattern unfeasible...?