# Why might a string not be equal to a stored varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query returns no results:

```
select *
from MyTable
where MyVarChar = '99903'
```

MyVarChar is a `varchar(20) not null` column.

The following data is stored in the table (a la 'select *'):

```
Id    MyVarChar
1     99901
2     99902
3     99903
```

Intriguingly, if I supply '99901' or '99902' in the comparison, I get a result.

I've tried `ltrim` and `rtrim` on both sides of the comparison with no success.

I'm... confounded. :P Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there isn't a non-printable character within the record for 99903?  Like a tab or something...

Comment: I'm not. But how would I go about testing for that? (Beyond the trim operations?)

Comment: You could test that by `SELECT MyVarChar, LEN(MyVarChar) FROM MyTable`. You should have only 5 in the second column of the result.

Comment: Use ASCII() to inspect the character value

Comment: Doh! It's been a long day. :) Thanks. I'll check and see.

Comment: If you need to trim Unicode whitespace have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245812/whats-a-good-way-to-trim-all-whitespace-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql-witho/35247507#35247507) answer.

Comment: fyi: [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) ignores trailing blanks. Since you've already checked with `RTRIM`, trincot's test is applicable. The alternative to `LEN` is `DATALENGTH` which returns the number of _bytes_. For Unicode strings you can use `DataLength( MyNVarChar ) / DataLength( NChar( 42 ) )` to get the number of characters.

Comment: I'd use `SELECT CAST(MyVarChar as varbinary(max))` to see the actual value in the column. With simple `SELECT` it is hard to notice non-printable characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the cast to `varbinary(max)` suggested by @Vladimir showed the hidden whitespace: it turned out to be a `CR+LF` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyVarChar LIKE '%99903%';
```

That will return anything with 99903 in it, so if you've got extra stuff on the end (or in front), it will still work.  `RTRIM()` and `LTRIM()` should have fixed that for you though.