# SQL REPLACE not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table that I'm trying to eliminate all the white spaces from a specific column. However my replace isn't working at all. Here's the code I have

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attempt1temptable') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #attempt1temptable
END
GO 

CREATE TABLE #attempt1temptable
(
   temp_description            varchar(MAX),
   temp_definition             varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #attempt1temptable
 SELECT  graphic_description, graphic_definition
 FROM graphic

UPDATE #attempt1temptable SET  temp_description=REPLACE(temp_description, ' ', '')
UPDATE #attempt1temptable SET  temp_description=REPLACE(temp_description,  char(160), '')

--I have no idea why it won't update correctly here

select temp_description, LEN(temp_description) from #attempt1temptable
```

The Insert and select work as expected however it's not updating temp_description to have no white spaces. The result of the query gives me the temp_description without anything changed to it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Ok you are updating the `temp_description` and selecting the `temp_definition` ... are you sure your updates aren't working?

Comment: Are you sure they are spaces and not some other white space character? Like a tab maybe?

Comment: That's exactly what it was, the row result was so long that I had trouble figuring out that in some spaces it was a tab rather than a space. @SeanLange

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247507/92546) answer may help with future battles against whitespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing some other whitespace characters:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(
   description
  ,char(9)/*tab*/,'')
  ,char(10)/*newline*/,'')
  ,char(13)/*carriage return*/,'')
  ,char(32)/*space*/,'')
from #attemp1temptable
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably dealing with other characters than `space`. You could be dealing with `tab` for example.
I would suggest to copy and paste the character to remove from the actual data into your replace statement to ensure you have the right character(s).

## Edit :

Also, you seem to use `LEN` to verify if the data was updated or not. However, keep in mind that `LEN` doesn't count trailing white space as character. So the count might not change even if the data was updated

Comment: [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql) ignores trailing blanks, but _does_ count leading blanks. [`DataLength()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) does not ignore blanks, but returns the number of bytes, not characters. For Unicode strings the length may be obtained using `DataLength( @Foo ) / DataLength( N'x' )`.