# Trying to convert a blank value to null in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to handle a blank or '' value to change to NULL while doing a simple select, but it is not working.

```
select distinct case when [Manager]='' then null else [Manager] end as Mgr from Table
where [Manager] in ('Abc', 'bas', 'xyz', 'pqr', '')
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Please show the incorrect results you are getting.

Comment: Do you simply want to eliminate `''` and `NULL` from the output of your `DISTINCT` query?

Comment: missing a TRIM() maybe?

Comment: Your code does what you state you want it to. I am guessing you have some other white space characters in your actual data.

Comment: The comments on one of the answers is right. We need DDL and DML that replicates this issue. Clearly there is more to this than the the little we've been given let's on.

Comment: If the problem is _variegated whitespace_, e.g. blanks, tabs, non-breaking spaces, ..., then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245812/whats-a-good-way-to-trim-all-whitespace-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql-witho/35247507#35247507) answer may help.

Comment: Yeah. You don't have a query problem. You have a data problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you also need to check null values with `OR [Manager] IS NULL`

```
select 
    distinct case when [Manager]='' then null else [Manager] end as Mgr 
from Table
where 
    [Manager] in ('Abc', 'bas', 'xyz', 'pqr', '')
    OR [Manager] IS NULL
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `WHERE ISNULL([Manager]),'') IN ('Abc', 'bas', 'xyz', 'pqr', '')`?

Comment: because of performance. if any index exist on manager column, isnull can make the index useless.

Comment: Good point. I found this over on dba.stackexchange.com via a Brent Ozar blog post. It has some interesting info on this subject: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168276/what-are-different-ways-to-replace-isnull-in-a-where-clause-that-uses-only-lit

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there's a million ways to do it, and someone did point out correctly that the function in the where clause eliminates the use of an index.

But what is happening in my query is I am removing any whitespace surrounding the field (the two trims), then the isnull says, if you find a null value then set it to ''. I do this to only have one statement, alternatively you could get rid of the isnull and say "Or [manager] is null". The select is saying trim manager and if it's blank (nullif) set it to null which is the expected outcome if I understood correctly.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM([manager])),'') AS Mgr
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM([manager])),'') IN ('Abc','bas','xyz','pqr','')
```

Comment: While your use of `NULLIF` is correct here, you could expand your answer a little to explain why your answer is correct.

Comment: Honestly there's a million ways to do it, and someone did point out correctly that the function in the where clause eliminates the use of an index.  But what is happening is I am removing any whitespace surrounding the field (the two trims), then the isnull says, if you find a null value then set it to ''.  I do this to only have one statement, alternatively you could get rid of the isnull and say "Or [manager] is null".  The select is saying trim manager and if it's blank (nullif) set it to null which is the expected outcome if I understood correctly.