# How to find/replace weird whitespace in string

Tags: t-sql

I find in my sql database string whit weird whitespace which cannot be replace like REPLACE(string, ' ', '') RTRIM and cant it even find with string = '% %'. This space is even transfered to new table when using SELECT string INTO
If i select this string in managment studio and copy that is seems is normal space and when everything is works but cant do nothing directly from database. What else can i do? Its some kind of error or can i try some special character for this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247507/92546) answer demonstrates a way of handling peculiar whitespace characters for left and right trimming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must identify the character.
You can do that by using a tally table (or a cte) and the [`Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

The following script will return a table with two columns: one contains a char and the other it's unicode value:

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(100) = N'This is a string containing 1 number and some words.';

with Tally(n) as
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM sys.objects a 
    --CROSS JOIN sys.objects b -- (unremark if there are not enough rows in the tally cte)
)

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@str, n, 1) As TheChar, 
        UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@str, n, 1)) As TheCode
FROM Tally
WHERE n <= LEN(@str)
```

You can also add a condition to the where clause to only include "special" chars:

```
AND SUBSTRING(@str, n, 1) NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Then you can replace it using it's unicode value using [`nchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (I've used 32 in this example since it's unicode "regular" space:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@str, NCHAR(32), '|')
```

Result:

```
This|is|a|string|containing|1|number|and|some|words.
```