# What is a good query to convert a space to an empty string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got this SQL query currently:

```
update con set lk = '' where datalength(lk) = 1 and lk = ' '
```

Is this the best query to convert any spaces (or other whitespace) to an empty string in MS SQL 2008 and above?

Comment: It's **best** to use a constraint and not allow that sort of thing in the first place.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35247507/92546) answer may help you with handling whitespace in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `trim()`:

```
update con
    set lk = ltrim(rtrim(lk))
    where ltrim(rtrim(lk)) <> lk;
```

That trims all values.  You can instead do:

```
update con
    set lk = ''
    where lk not like '%[^ ]%';  -- put all "white space" characters here
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `TRIM` for your case. Since you want to replace empty string so `LTRIM` or `RTRIM` both can work fine

```
update con set lk = '' where LTRIM(lk)=''
```

But if you have other then `space` in your string then this will not work. For more advance method you need this.

```
update con set lk = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(1k, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), ''))) 
where LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(1k, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')))=''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from con where lk like '% %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that the `LEN` of any string made up of only spaces will be 0, you can do this (no trimming or replacing required):

```
UPDATE con SET lk = ''
WHERE LEN(lk) + PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+']%',lk) = 0;
```

I included CHAR(9),10 & 11 in my code which is most common. You can get a complete list of Unicode whitespace characters [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). If you are are dealing with VARCHAR you only need to worry about CHAR's less than 255:  9,10,11,12,13,32,133,160.