# LTRIM does not remove leading space in SQL

Tags: t-sql, trim

I load data from a text file and it seems that it does not contain leading space, however when I SELECT from a table, I see the leading space but cannot remove it with a `LTRIM` function:

```
SELECT ltrim(DATA) FROM MYTABLE WHERE LineNumber = 4
```

I'm getting the following:

```
T000000000004
```

with a single leading space before T

When I do `select convert(varbinary,data) from mytable`, that's what I get:

```
0x0A54303030303030303030303034
```

In the file it looks ok: `T000000000004` - no leading space and it starts from the first character in the file. However, in the table it's inserted with a leading space.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It could be an invisible character that is not a white space, which is why LTRIM cannot remove it. Can you try getting the character code (ASCII/UNICODE) of that character? It might give you a lead to follow.

Comment: The example you have given us *does* have it removed [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2f4958d85927f53701c9def0662cb66). ACutally copy the value you receive, and show is your SQL with LTRIM

Comment: @Larnu That's because I typed it in here.

Comment: That's why I said *". ACutally copy the value you receive, and show is your SQL with LTRIM"* @gene . Your question doesn't replicate the problem, nor does it use `LTRIM`.

Comment: @Larnu I modified the question

Comment: The value is `'" T000000000004"'`. `LTRIM` only strips leading `' '` characters. `"` is the first character, so no whitespace is removed.

Comment: @Larnu Actually the string is T000000000004 without quotes. I put quotes for an example when was concatenating it before I changed the descriptcription of the problem

Comment: Again, that doesn't replciate the problem [db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0a328eb2efc4bdf02a25f7242255559).

Comment: @Larnu I cannot replicate the problem here. I'm explaining what is the problem. As I said there is some kind of character before the data and when I trim it, it does not get trimmed. How can I replicate it here if the character is interpreted differently then on my PC

Comment: If there *were* some kind of other character, then simply copy and pasting it into the question would copy it. The fact that when you copy it doesn't replicate it means that there's something you aren't telling us.

Comment: @Larnu I just copied the data as I got it from the select statement

Comment: @gene with the greatest respect, then the value you put in the post is not a copy, as it has the `varbinary` value `0x20202054303030303030303030303034`

Comment: FWIW: An example of trimming all .NET whitespace characters is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245812/whats-a-good-way-to-trim-all-whitespace-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql-witho/35247507#35247507). And `0x0A` is a linefeed character.

Comment: @Larnu  When I do `select convert(varbanary,data) from mytable` I have exactly what I posted in my description

Comment: Yes, but when ***we*** copy the data you supplied and do a `CONVERT` we don't get the same value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HABO mentioned, your value doesn't start with a space, it doesn't actually have any white space in it at all, it has a leading Line Feed (character 10, or `0X0A`).

To remove these, and any carriage returns you might have too, you can use `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(data,CHAR(10),'')),CHAR(13),'')
```

`(L/R)TRIM` only remove leading/trailing white space. Nothing else.

If there could be a range of leading characters, and you want to remove all of them up to say the first alphanumerical character, you can use `PATINDEX` and `STUFF`:

```
SELECT STUFF(V.[data],1,PATINDEX('%[A-z1-9]%',V.[data])-1,'')
FROM (VALUES(CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + '  -T000000129B'))V([data])
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the case actually