# Removing leading spaces off an INT (SQL), TRIMS don't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, trim, azure-synapse

I have a few rows of data which I need to check the following

1. if INT then produce the INT
2. if INT but with leading/trailing space, trim then produce INT
3. if not INT at all, then produce NULL

Here's the following data:

| Number |
| --- |
| 514449 |
| NA |
| NA |
| 609924 |
| 609923 |
| NA |

the table above doesn't show it, but there's a leading space on the first row that I just can't get rid of using traditional TRIMS

[image]

I've tried a solution from this question but no luck either: [LTRIM does not remove leading space in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855145/ltrim-does-not-remove-leading-space-in-sql)

Here's the CASE statement I've built so far which doesn't correctly identify the leading space in the first row of data

```sql
    CASE  
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(TRIM([Number])) = 0 THEN 'NOT INT' 
        WHEN [Number] LIKE ' %' THEN 'Leading Space' 
        WHEN substring([Number],1,1) = ' ' THEN 'Leading Space' 
        ELSE [Number] 
    END AS 'CHECK'
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246179/discussion-on-question-by-codingnoob-removing-leading-spaces-off-an-int-sql-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT` to attempt conversion to `int`, it will return `NULL` if it fails.

Your starting character is actually U+160 Non-Breaking Space. You can remove it using `REPLACE`

```sql
TRY_CONVERT(int, REPLACE(TRIM(YourValue), CHAR(160), ''))
```

In standard SQL Server you can also use `TRIM FROM`

```sql
TRY_CONVERT(int, TRIM(' ' + CHAR(160) FROM YourValue))
```