# SqlServer, how to replace all spaces sequences with only one

Tags: sql-server, regex

I would know if it possible (and how) replace all spaces secquence with only one.

I have following string: 
`'jkdhsf     sdf jkdsf  d fsjlk ds   d jldksf dsf    dòkjdkl ò'`

my goal is condensing multiple spces in only one like :

`'jkdhsf sdf jkdsf d fsjlk ds d jldksf dsf dòkjdkl ò'`

I know that I can use nested replace like :

```
Select 
  replace(
    replace(
      replace(
        replace('jkdhsf     sdf jkdsf  d fsjlk ds   d jldksf dsf    dòkjdkl ò', '     ',1)
      , '    ',1)
     , '   ',1)
    , '  ',1) ...
```

but I don't know maximum number of spaces I have in my string.

So, I'm thinking to something like replace function that using regular expression matching each space repetition...

I use SqlServer 2008 R2.

Comment: What is your required output?

Comment: TSQL does not support regex patterns, and there is no quantifier support in TSQL patterns. You need a custom CLR function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/remove-all-spaces-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql)

Comment: It is a duplicate of question [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(1000)
SET @test = 'jkdhsf    sdf     jkdsf d     fsjlk ds d jldksf dsf dòkjdkl ò'

WHILE CHARINDEX('  ',@test  ) > 0
BEGIN
   SET @test = REPLACE(@test, '  ', ' ')
END

SELECT @test
```

Comment: And that will replace all spaces with `1`. OP needs to normalize spaces, not replace them with another value.

Comment: Any difference from this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2455880/2893376