# Is it possible to use Trim function for join with space in the middle?

Tags: sql, join, trim

How can I use trim, or another function, to remove a space in the middle of a column that I am trying to join 2 tables on?

```
Ex:
....from Stage.FactTravelIBank ft
     join Dim.Mileage m
      on m.market = ft.itinerary
```

where table m has market abcdef and ft has itinerary abc def

I've only been able to find examples where trim is used with spaced at the beginning or end, or is trimming a character.

Comment: Have you considered `replace(ft.itinerary,' ','')` ?

Comment: TRIM does only remove leading and trailing characters, not somewhere in the middle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/remove-all-spaces-from-a-string-in-sql-server/10432124 would work.

Comment: By the way, if you are joining on mutated strings... you are going to have performance issues. The database should be designed in a relational way that allows joining tables without string manipulation.

Comment: Even if possible I would consider this an unreliable query. I would better do a data clean up.

Comment: @Aron Yes I think this will work, Thanks!