# Remove ALL white spaces in a string sql server

Tags: sql-server, whitespace

I'm trying to convert this '232431 K' into this '232431K' and I can't find a function that does this. All the references I have found are TRIM, RTRIM and LTRIM but these functions are not useful for me in this case because I don't have left or right white spaces to be removed, the white spaces are "inside" the string.

Comment: You're trying to replace characters in strings, not trim them. Use `REPLACE(somField,' ','')`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using `replace`, on SQL Server 2017+ to avoid multiple nested functions, you can use `translate` if there are multiple characters in a string you want to remove:

Remove space, hyphen, slash:

```
declare @string varchar(50)='12345 67-9\x'

select Replace(Translate(@string, ' -\','???'),'?','')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to [Remove all spaces from a string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/remove-all-spaces-from-a-string-in-sql-server).

In simple terms, you will need to use `REPLACE` function, such as `REPLACE(stringValue, ' ', '')`

Comment: I see, thanks. What if I have to replace ' ' or '-', is it possible to put it all using just one REPLACE function? For example REPLACE(stringValue, [' ', '-'], '')

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like below

```
SELECT  REPLACE(N'232431 K',' ','')
```

As asked in another comment

> What if I have to replace ' ' or '-', is it possible to put it all using just one REPLACE function? For example REPLACE(stringValue, [' ', '-'], '')

you should use replace in conjuction with Translate function

```
select replace(translate (N'l;[pi-',';[-','   '),' ','')
```