# LTRIM/RTRIM not removing spaces

Tags: t-sql

using the script:

```
select 'XX' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Account_No))  
from mis.ahr.Arnel_Apple_BID_VPP_List2014Oct
where Account_No LIKE '%32216996%'
```

I still get

```
(No column name)
XX 32216996
```

what could be the cause? TIA

Comment: What is the column type of `Account_No`?

Comment: its varchar @Jason C

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL 2008 Using LTrim(RTrim and still have spaces in the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374888/tsql-2008-using-ltrimrtrim-and-still-have-spaces-in-the-data)

Comment: Are you sure it's a space and not a tab?

Comment: (Or a no-break space, or anything else like that; see linked question.)

Comment: I've had that problem. Try for nb-space. Tabs are trimmed i believe but not nbsps (ascii code 160). Add a REPLACE(Account_No, CHAR(160), '') and it will probably work.

Comment: okay thanks for all the suggestions! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try this to see what character it is

```
select unicode(LEFT(Account_No,1)) 
from mis.ahr.Arnel_Apple_BID_VPP_List2014Oct
where Account_No LIKE '%32216996%'
```

Then use `nchar( n)` for replace

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, and let us know what 'Account_No' and 'hexBytes' columns show :

```
select Account_No,  
cast(Account_No as varbinary(500)) as hexBytes
from mis.ahr.Arnel_Apple_BID_VPP_List2014Oct
where Account_No LIKE '%32216996%'
```

This will show you what exactly is in Account_No.