# LTRIM usage with SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am a bit of an sql noob so please forgive. I can't seem to find a usage example of LTRIM anywhere.

I have a NVARCHAR column in my table in which a number of entries have leading whitespace - I'm presuming if I run this it should do the trick:

```
SELECT LTRIM( ColumnName)
  From TableName;
```

Will this give the desired result?

Comment: edit: What I am hoping to achieve is to update the records. The above just selects and trims. Select, trim and update accordingly is what I am looking for.

Comment: Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864838/remove-trailing-empty-space-in-a-field-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will trim leading spaces but not all white space (e.g. carriage returns).

**Edit**
It seems you are looking for an `UPDATE` query that will remove leading and trailing whitespace.

If by that you only mean "normal" spaces just use

```
    UPDATE TableName
   SET ColumnName = LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnName ))
```

For all white space this should do it (from [the comments](http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com/2006/03/remove-carriage-return-line-feed-tab.html) here). Backup your data first!

```
    UPDATE TableName
   SET ColumnName = 
     SUBSTRING(
    ColumnName,
    PATINDEX('%[^ ' + char(09) + char(10) + char(13)  + char(20)  + ']%', 
    ColumnName),
    LEN(ColumnName) - PATINDEX('%[^ ' + char(09) + char(10) + char(13)  + char(20)  + ']%'
   , ColumnName) - 
    PATINDEX('%[^ ' + char(09) + char(10) + char(13)  + char(20)  + ']%', 
     REVERSE(ColumnName)) + 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example will work to remove the leading spaces.  This will only select it from the database.  IF you need to actually change the data in your table, you will need to write an UPDATE statement something like:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET ColumnName = LTRIM(ColumnName)
```

If you need to remove spaces from the right side, you can use RTRIM.

Here is a list of the string functions in SQL Server 2005 that I always refer to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that link will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run it to find out?  It's just a select, it won't blow up your database.  But, yes.

```
Select LTRIM(myColumn) myColumn
From   myTable
```

Should return the `myColumn` values with any leading whitespace removed.  Note this is only leading whitespace.

**EDIT** To Update the column, with the above, you'd do:

```
Update myTable
Set myColumn = LTRIM(myColumn)
From myTable
```

Comment: I take it I would do an RTrim to clean up the right side too.

Comment: @Chin - yes.  I believe there is also a TRIM() function (but its been too long since I've looked, so I'm not 100% sure) which would trim both leading and trailing spaces.  And the other gentlemen are correct, it won't remove carriage returns.

Comment: TSQL doesn't have a TRIM() - just RTRIM and LTRIM.  You want TRIM, got to use UDF or CLR...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Okay, I remember now.  We always used LTRIM(RTRIM(column)).  Like I said, been too long since I've used the functions at all...