# Refactoring - two horrid lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been working on a stored procedure and hit a point where I have two really horrid lines. Is there a way to re-write this in a clearer way within the stored procedure? If not, how would I go about creating a function to do this?

```
, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(l.tenant_trading_name,'~','-'), '"','-'), '#','-'), '%','-'), '*','-'), ':','-'), '<','-'), '>','-'), '?','-'), '/','-'), '\','-'), '{','-'), '|','-'), '}','-') as trading_name
    ,   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(l.suite_name,'&','-'), '~','-'), '"','-'), '#','-'), '%','-'), '*','-'), ':','-'), '<','-'), '>','-'), '?','-'), '/','-'), '\','-'), '{','-'), '|','-'), '}','-') as suite_name
```

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864838/remove-trailing-empty-space-in-a-field-content

Comment: Just an idea: since T-SQL basically sucks at string manipulation: how about creating a "string helper" assembly in C# and including it into SQL Server using the SQL CLR ? The .NET stuff for string manipulation is just that much more powerful (and easier to use!) than T-SQL's limited capabilities...

Comment: @marc_s Intriguing, hadn't considered it. Will look into it more and explore it as an option. Thank-you very much

Comment: +1 for C#. This is a perfect example where SQL per se just totally sucks. SQL CLR And one can use a nice regex and do all that in one run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could simply have a function that does the dirty work for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanCharacters
(
  @InputString VARCHAR(64),
  @UseAmp BIT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(64)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(...REPLACE(
      @InputString, CASE WHEN @UseAmp = 1 THEN '&' ELSE '-' END, '-'),
      '~', '')...etc etc...)))
  );
END
GO
```

Then you can say:

```
SELECT dbo.CleanCharacters(l.tenant_trading_name, 0),
dbo.CleanCharacters(l.suite_name, 1) FROM ...
```

This at least abstracts the ugly `REPLACE()` calls out of the procedure.

(Note that I didn't quite parse the entire line to see if there were other differences but it seemed to me that the only difference was the suite_name couldn't have an & but the trading name could.)

Another way would be to store your "bad" characters in a table, making maintenance of those replacements a little easier (and once the table is populated, making the function much cleaner as well).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DirtyCharacters(x CHAR(1));

INSERT dbo.DirtyCharacters SELECT '~' 
  UNION ALL SELECT '&' 
  UNION ALL SELECT '*'
-- ...
;
```

Now you can have your function simply say:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CleanCharacters
(
  @InputString VARCHAR(64),
  @UseAmp BIT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(64)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, x, '-')
    FROM dbo.DirtyCharacters 
    WHERE x <> CASE WHEN @UseAmp = 1 THEN '' ELSE '&' END;

  RETURN (@InputString);
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it works for your first string for example.

```
 SELECT @Str = REPLACE( @Str , chr , '-' )
      FROM ( SELECT '~' UNION 
         SELECT '"' UNION 
         SELECT '#' UNION
              SELECT '%' UNION 
              SELECT '*' UNION 
              SELECT ':' UNION
              SELECT '<' UNION  
              SELECT '>' UNION  
              SELECT '?' UNION  
              SELECT '/' UNION  
              SELECT '\' UNION  
              SELECT '{' UNION  
              SELECT '|' UNION  
              SELECT '}' UNION  
              SELECT '%' ) D ( chr )
     WHERE CHARINDEX( chr , @Str ) > 0 ;
    SELECT @str ;
```

Comment: Two quick comments: (1) I'm not sure that's any prettier for the query than all the `REPLACE` lines, and (2) I doubt a variable assignment is valid here if this is part of a `SELECT` list on a multi-row query.